# Pathname property in IBM FileNet P8 backend database

Tags: sql, ecm, filenet-p8, filenet

Appreciate if anyone can tell me which table "PathName" property exists in the backend database of IBM Filenet P8 ECM system.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Why are you going directly against the database? The schema might change in the next version. Why not just query this information using on of the API's?

Comment: That's a valid question. But at the moment, I am doing some special work on only one set of servers.

Answer (score 1):

just for your understanding.

PathName is not simple property like others. It is not present in full form in tables.

Path of Document can have multiple values, cause of document from [DocVersion] table (and custom object from [Generic] table) link with the Folder placed in [Container] table through ReferencialContainmentRelationship object in [Relationship] table.

So you can get the PathName for Document as concatinations of Relationship.Name (ContainmentName) and Container.**PathName (*** + FolderName) where Relationship.Tail_Id equals DocVersion.Object_Id and Container.Object_Id equals Relationship.Head_Id

You have to use recursion for get Container.**PathName cause of you need to get all parent objects [Container.Parent_Id == (Parent)Container.Object_Id].

Threre is the link for documentation with Tables overview 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/database_table_schemas.htm

But, you have to find another way to get PathName, Tom Purl was right try to query this information via API.

Comment: We did this with Filenet P8 4.5 that uses DB2. The major advantage is speed:FEM took hours, a SQL query less than a minute.